# How to schedule a SharePoint Online Powershell script to run everyday?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, schedule

We have been scheduling SharePoint on-prem Powershell scripts using Windows Task Scheduler to run at a specific time

But how do i schedule a SharePoint Online Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/) is an option if you're looking to run scripts directly in the cloud.

Simply create a runbook for your powershell script, and setup a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the same technique windows task scheduler job for SharePoint online the way we used to in SharePoint On-Premise. The only notable thing is - the account what you are configuring in Windows task scheduler to run the script should not be **MFA** enabled and the script must be developed in PowerShell CSOM or PnP.